# trying to += element to custom array class in python sets object to nonetype

Tags: python

So, Ruby. Ruby is great. Buuuut, its graphic library choices aren't that good. Python, I've heard, is all around excellent ... and I mostly agree, I've used it before! But can you do this

```
class Numeric
    def first_digit
        return self.to_s[0]
    end
end

puts 50834.first_digit
```

in Python? No. Which is why I'm trying to make my own custom Ruby-esque basic classes in Python; so I can have the versatility of the latter while taking advantage of the ability to make useful custom methods like those I can implement in the former.

```
# Classes
# number [int or float] -- planning to make derivative Integer and Float classes later
# string -- string
# boolean -- boolean
# array -- list
# [going to make]
# hashmap -- dict
# color -- rgb, hsv, etc
# imaginary -- for imaginary numbers
# based_number -- for conversions and operations between numbers of a certain base
```

It's the array class I'm having trouble with (for reference, pyro is the module name). Here’s the code.

```
class array:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.raw = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.raw)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"pyro.array({self.raw})"
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.raw[value]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.raw[index] = value
    def __add__(self, thing):
        return array(self.raw + [thing])
    def __iadd__(self, thing):
        self.raw = self.raw + [thing]
```

```
#Some notes ...

# __init__() initializes the object, __str__ returns stringified object, __repr__ returns representation of object.
# Overloads:
# __getitem__ overloads baz[n]
# __setitem__ overloads baz[n] = "nuz"
# __add__ overloads + operator
# __iadd__ overloads += operator
```

Here’s the crux of the issue, in a code example

```
import os
from pyro import number, boolean, string, array
os.system("color")

array_yay = array(["spam", "eggs"])
print("If I do " + "\x1b[38;5;202m" + "arrayThingy = arrayThingy + value" + "\x1b[0m" + " everything is okay.")
print("This is array_yay now ... " + str(array_yay))
print("Adding baz to array the good way")
array_yay = array_yay + "baz"
print("Voilà! Here we have " + str(array_yay))
print("Now I'll try to add blox the bad way ...")
array_yay += "blox"
print("ARRGH! LOOK! NOW array_yay is " + str(array_yay))
```

Output in command prompt:

[image: woog]

```
# Transcription

# If I do *arrayThingy = arrayThingy + value* everything is okay.
# This is array_yay now ... ['spam', 'eggs']
# Adding baz to array the good way
# Voilà! Here we have ['spam', 'eggs', 'baz']
# Now I'll try to add blox the bad way ...
# ARRGH! LOOK! NOW array_yay is None
``
```

Comment: This is going to cause a *lot* more problems than it solves. The standard library, the language core, and all your dependencies are going to be written in terms of the actual built-in classes, not your replacements. You'll have endless issues with interoperability.

Comment: I would just generalize your coding thought process to be flexible enough to allow for writing first_digit(50834) instead of 50834.first_digit. Its changing the order and using parentheses instead of a dot - you are doing a lot of work for very little benefit. first_digit = lambda n: str(n)[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `self` from `__iadd__`. `__iadd__` is allowed to return arbitrary objects (though returning anything but `self` is highly unusual), and by implicitly returning `None`, you're saying that `array_yay` should be `None` after `array_yay += "blox"`.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why ```self``` needs to be returned? Just trying to grow as a programmer ...

Comment: @JoJodaMan: The return value is the thing that gets assigned to the augmented assignment target.